# Insert into value of Radio button

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I am trying to insert the value of a radio button when its checked into mysql db table.  Below is the HTML and the PHP for doing so.  Please let me know what is going wrong?

> Here is the HTML first:

```
<div class='container'>
    <label for='username' >Business*:</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="bus" id="username" value="bus" maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='username' >Personal*:</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="pers" id="username" value="per" maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='register_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
```

> Now the PHP:

```
function InsertIntoDB(&$formvars)
    {

        $confirmcode = $this->MakeConfirmationMd5($formvars['email']);

        $formvars['confirmcode'] = $confirmcode;

        $insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
                name,
                email,
                username,
                password,
                confirmcode,
                dob,
                business,
                personal
                )
                values
                (
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['name']) . '",
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
                "' . md5($formvars['password']) . '",
                "' . $confirmcode . '",
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['dob']) . '",
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['bus']) . '",
                "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['pers']) . '"
                )';      
        if(!mysql_query( $insert_query ,$this->connection))
        {
            $this->HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\nquery:$insert_query");
            return false;
        }        
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440425/how-to-display-radio-button-value-using-php?rq=1

Comment: that was not even close to what i was asking.

Comment: Are neither of that radio values showing up in the database after submitting?

Comment: correct sbeliv01, the values dont make it to the database whether checked or not.

Comment: Nevermind, Variable wasnt defined for the radio field.  Sorry for the time wasted. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a logical error. You should only save one of the variable in radio button in database.

> ```
>             "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['bus']) . '",
>            "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['pers']) . '"
> ```